# Cross stack-reference from different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have two stacks - A & B, but they are in different AWS accounts. I want to export a resource(log) of stack A to stack B. Since it is cross-account, the normal stack referencing method won't work. I am trying to figure out the best way to do this.

If anyone has worked on this before, please do share how you implemented it.

Answer (score 5):

Cross-account and cross-region export/imports are **not supported** in CloudFormation. If you want to have everything done automatically, you would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in stack B in the form of a lambda function. The function would have to be able to access and query the stack in A in different account, and return desired attributes to stack B.

Alternatively, you could store the attributes from stack A in a [parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) created in Acc B and use [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html) in stack B to fetch the values from the store.

Other option is to **parametrize** stack B, and "manually" (could be through AWS CLI or SDK script) pass required attributes from stack A as parameters into the stack B.

Comment: Just a note to say SSM doesn't support cross-account access, at least not without assuming a role across accounts first. It is possible with Secrets Manager.